# How to plot a table of table?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving

```
soln = DSolve[y''[x] + y'[x] + y[x] == 0, y[x], x]
solTable = 
 Table[soln /. {C[1] -> i, C[2] -> j}, {i, -1, 1, 1}, {j, -1, 1, 1}]
Plot[solTable, {x, -2, 4}]
```

I am trying to generate the plot of the table but nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
soln = DSolveValue[y''[x] + y'[x] + y[x] == 0, y[x], x];
solTable = 
  Table[soln /. {C[1] -> i, C[2] -> j}, {i, -1, 1, 1}, {j, -1, 1, 
    1}];
Plot[solTable, {x, -2, 4}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

soln = DSolveValue[y''[x] + y'[x] + y[x] == 0, y[x], x];
```

[`Flatten`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html) the [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) to get individual colors

```
solTable = Flatten[Table[Tooltip[soln /. {C[1] -> i, C[2] -> j},
     StringForm["``=``, ``=``", C[1], i, C[2], j]],
    {i, -1, 1, 1}, {j, -1, 1, 1}], 1];

Plot[solTable, {x, -2, 4},
 PlotLabel -> soln,
 PlotLegends -> Flatten[Table[
    StringForm["``=``, ``=``", C[1], i, C[2], j],
    {i, -1, 1, 1}, {j, -1, 1, 1}],
   1]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
soln = DSolve[y''[x] + y'[x] + y[x] == 0, y[x], x]
solTable = 
 y[x] /. Table[
   soln /. {C[1] -> i, C[2] -> j}, {i, -1, 1, 1}, {j, -1, 1, 1}];
Plot[solTable, {x, -2, 4}]
```

[image]